# Azure DevOps Pipeline: exclude paths for PRs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I'd like to *only* have CI builds on PRs to `master` and can't figure out how to specify that in the yaml.

My last try was:

```yaml
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    exclude:
      - docs/
      - README.md
      - CHANGELOG.md
      - COPYING
      - .circleci
      - test/
      - run_route_scripts/
      - docker/
      - .github/
  drafts: false
```

which *should work* according to [Azure's DevOps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers). I let the change in azure config fully run on CI, then I committed only to `CHANGELOG.md` which triggered another build where it shouldn't have..

**Note**, I did not include a `trigger` section, as this repo practically never receives any commits to `master` unless it came from a PR, and I'm not sure what the side effects might be..

See the full yaml here: https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla/blob/nn_win_skip_ci/.azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: PR triggers in YAML are for repos hosted in **GitHub**, not in Azure DevOps. For repos hosted in Azure DevOps, use branch policies. Also, look at the documentation on the `trigger` section: Not including a `trigger` at all will default to running on **every commit** to **every branch**. Specify `trigger: none` if you want to *never* trigger on commit. You indicated that you knew it might be a problem but didn't check if it would be -- that would have been a great place to start investigating independently before asking a question here.

Comment: Sorry, premature: Thanks for chiming in. It’s true, thinking about it more: if a PR comes from the same repo, it triggers if push triggers are not excluded in the config yaml. Only a PR from a fork should be excluded with the pattern above right? Ill try a trigger: none, thanks. BTW, the repo is hosted on GitHub as you can see in the link to the repo. And I did check about triggers, but didn’t think about in-repo vs fork PRs. I wonder if in-repo PR are covered by the pr section at all.. Probably not.. I thats not very clear from the documentation I think..

Comment: Yes, that did work. And it does make total sense. Also, in-repo PRs are covered by the `pr` rules, only the included target branches matter. The docu is actually pretty clear about that. Thanks @DanielMann, if you want to answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Hi @nnolde, You could also share your answer below and accept it, it could help other community members who get the same issues. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)